# SQL Update table select from other table

Tags: sql

i want to update multiple value of my table ORDRE ?

table ORDRE

```
CP   INSEE  What
--   -----  ----
1    null   Cake
2    null   Coki
3    null   Lopi
```

table TheINSEE

```
  CP   INSEE
  --   -----
  1    a
  2    b
  3    c
```

how can update my table ordre to get like this?

```
CP   INSEE  What
--   -----  ----
1    a      Cake
2    b      Coki
3    c      Lopi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
update ORDRE
set o.INSEE = i.INSEE
from ORDRE o
inner join TheINSEE i on i.CP = o.CP
```